# How do I create polar charts with highcharts-react-official?

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I am trying to create a polar chart using the `highcharts-react-official` HighchartsReact wrapper. However, I get a regular line chart or errors. How do I use the `highcharts/highcharts-more` features with the HighchartsReact wrapper?

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsMore from 'highcharts/highcharts-more'
import HighchartsReact from './HighchartsReact';

HighchartsMore(Highcharts)

const options = {
  chart: {
    type: 'polar',
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Kahn Chart'
  },
  pane: {
    startAngle: 0,
    endAngle: 360
  },
  xAxis: {
    tickInterval: 90,
    min: 0,
    max: 360,
    labels: {
      format: '{value}°'
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      pointStart: 0,
      pointInterval: 90
    },
    column: {
      pointPadding: 0,
      groupPadding: 0
    }
  },
  series: [
    {
      type: 'area',
      name: 'c1',
      data: [7.15, 10,  9.85, 8.81],
    },
    {
      type: 'line',
      name: 'c2',
      data: [4.65, 3.16, 4.30, 4.48],
    },
    {
      type: 'line',
      name: 'Fair Value',
      data: [4.77,6.67, 6.57, 5.87],
    }
  ]
};

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={options} />
  </div>
);

render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change:

```
chart: {
    type: 'polar',
},
```

To:

```
chart: {
    polar: true
},
```

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.polar

Comment: Thanks, that fixed my problem

Comment: Hi softweave, Here you can find an example of  `polar` chart with React: https://codesandbox.io/s/ovx6kqokqq